# sql statement to return all fields from all tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
select * from *
```

yes this is what I want I want to return all fields from all table in my **ACCESS database** regardless the fields names or the tables names!!!

for example if I have table1 and table2 as tables in my database access file
what I want is to generate this statement

```
 select * from table1,table2
```

from sql query which run fine in access query

but again I don't know the name of the tables which in the access file.

is there a way for that?

Comment: When you say return, return as what? And from VBA?

Comment: I want the statement to run with no errors, in access query "sql view" editor, this will let me gain what I want in the Microsoft Query editor.

*return as result set.
*it will be used in Excel vba code but my scope here is to let it work in sql code for access query.

Comment: Have a look at http://p2p.wrox.com/vb-databases-basics/66598-vbulletin-net-ms-access-list-column-names-how-sample.html. This allows you to get the Field Names per table in VBA.

Comment: Does the table that you want have any particular field names? Does the table name have a pattern, such as month + year or username + 1, for example? If you supply more details, it may be possible to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I know nothing about these tables which may or may not be there. I just want all tables in the database which is not sys. tables.

Comment: You want all tables in a single SQL FROM clause? You do realize that without JOINs defined, you'll end up with a Cartesian product, which could mean returning millions of records? And likely, you'd run out of temp space before it could complete? What is it that you're really trying to accomplish? You clearly don't want to do what you're actually asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will list all the table names

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=6))
```

You can also use this bit of code to go through every table and list every field

```
Public Sub List_fields_in_tables()
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field

For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        Debug.Print "Table='" & tdf.name & "'  Field='" & fld.name & "'"

    Next fld

Next tdf

End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you should use from `Master` database in SQL Server

`Master` database contains information about all columns of all of your databases. also there is catalog view to gain information about an exact database.

Just use Master stored procedures

Comment: The questions states MS Access.